# Why does the implementation of `FromIterator` use an `IntoIterator` instead of an `Iterator`?

Tags: iterator, rust

The example implementation of the `FromIterator` trait in the [Rust docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.FromIterator.html) is:

```
impl FromIterator<i32> for MyCollection {
    fn from_iter<I: IntoIterator<Item=i32>>(iter: I) -> Self {
        let mut c = MyCollection::new();

        for i in iter {
            c.add(i);
        }

        c
    }
}
```

`FromIterator` defines how a type will be created from an iterator. The signature of `from_iter` requires a type that implements `IntoIterator`, which defines how a type may be converted into an `Iterator`.

Is `from_iter` defined this way because `IntoIterator` is not as strict a requirement as `Iterator`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is `from_iter` defined this way because `IntoIterator` is not as strict a requirement as `Iterator`?

Yes.

`IntoIterator` is automatically implemented for `Iterator`, therefore the set of types implementing `IntoIterator` is a superset of those implementing `Iterator`.

When crafting a generic function, it's good to minimize its requirements, i.e., make it as generic as possible.

Of course, there's a trade-off between:

- *ease of use*: works with as many types as possible,
- *ease of implementation*.

For a lone function in your isolated codebase, it may not be worth optimizing for ease-of-use much; for a trait/function in the standard library, since the number of users far outweigh the number of developers (of this particular piece), the trade-off is strongly in favor of ease-of-use.

And since going from `IntoIterator` to `Iterator` is so simple, and thus doesn't weigh much on the implementation, it's an easy call to make.