# Iterator vs IntoIterator for flatten

Tags: rust, iterator

I'm playing around with iterators and I've been using `Flatten` to better understand how iterators work. This example:

```
assert_eq!(vec![1, 2].iter().flatten().count(), 2);
```

Does not compile and gives the error (well the primary error of concern):

```
error[E0277]: `&{integer}` is not an iterator
  --> src/lib.rs:59:38
   |
59 |         assert_eq!(vec![1, 2].iter().flatten().count(), 2);
   |                                      ^^^^^^^ `&{integer}` is not an iterator
   |
   = help: the trait `std::iter::Iterator` is not implemented for `&{integer}`
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `std::iter::IntoIterator` for `&{integer}`
```

What confuses me is that it looks like `Flatten` requires the nested `Item` to implement `IntoIterator`. I confirmed this in the rustdocs, where they declare

```
pub struct Flatten<I> 
where
    I: Iterator,
    <I as Iterator>::Item: IntoIterator
```

Just from ready the docs, IntoIterator just provides a way to define how a type is converted into an iterator. Why couldn't the trait bound be `<I as Iterator>::Item: Iterator`? Surely if the nested item implements `Iterator`, then we get the same `Flatten` since the nested item's must be iterators themselves. What difference/benefit does it bring to use `IntoIterator` instead?

Comment: The question is reasonable, but it seems to have nothing to do with the error message.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does the implementation of \`FromIterator\` use an \`IntoIterator\` instead of an \`Iterator\`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48977251/why-does-the-implementation-of-fromiterator-use-an-intoiterator-instead-of-a)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Requiring `IntoIterator` rather than `Iterator` lets you flatten a collection of collections in addition to a collection of iterators.

The collection type, for example `Vec`, is different from the iterator type, so if `flatten` required the items to be `Iterator`s you couldn't flatten a `Vec` of `Vec`s.

`IntoIterator` represents a type that can be *converted* into an iterator, such as a `Vec` or many other collections (or an iterator!). So this, for example, works:

```
fn main() {
    let nested_vec: Vec<Vec<i32>> = vec![vec![1, 2], vec![3, 4]];
    let flat_vec: Vec<i32> = nested_vec.into_iter().flatten().collect();
    println!("{:?}", flat_vec);
}
```

You can [try this example on the Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=aa774ffd025bfb65368d5b6b689d8e4a). Using `into_iter()` above instead of `iter()` makes sure we iterate over `i32`s, not *references* to `i32`s. (Thanks Cerberus for suggesting `into_iter()` instead of `copied()`.)

(You can see a few more types with `IntoIterator` implementations [in the docs' "Implementations on Foreign Types" section](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.IntoIterator.html#foreign-impls).)

Comment: You could also replace `iter` with `into_iter` instead of adding `copied`.

Comment: Ah, I can't believe that went over my head! Thanks

Comment: @Cerberus Thanks--example now uses `into_iter`.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that every `Iterator` automatically implements `IntoIterator` (triviallly returning self), so requiring `IntoIterator` covers the iterators as well as collections. To clarify I propose changing "rather than" to "in addition to" in the first sentence.

Comment: @user4815162342 Thanks. (I had it that way in the first revision, don't recall why I changed it.)